# How do `subxt` and `substrate-api-client` libraries differ?

Tags: rust, rpc, subxt, client, substrate-api-client

I understand that there are two main Rust client libraries for Substrate:

- `subxt`
- `substrate-api-client`

I've checked out the examples for both libraries and it seems to me that they are mostly the same.

From what I understand `substrate-api-client` is a web3 foundation grant recipient and `subxt` is the library built by Parity Technologies.

That said, I couldn't find any direct comparisons or information about the pros and cons of each library and why you would use one over the other (or maybe one is simply better than the other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not used substrate-api-client yet, but I think one distinguishing feature is autogeneration of code from metadata is something that subxt has put a lot of effort into.

substrate-api-client supports `no_std` which subxt does not ([yet](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/484)).

Comment: Is substrate_api_client different from polkadot_js_api_client?